# How do I add -v to XCode 4.4 compile?

Tags: xcode, linker-errors

I'm trying to find the source of a linker error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm trying to add -v as a command line parameter, but in **Product / Edit Scheme : Build** I see no option to do so

Answer (score 0):

Xcode's build transcript will let you see the linker command so you can see what caused the linker to fail. Open the log navigator by choosing View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator. Select your build from the log navigator to open the build results window. Select the link step from the build results window. Click the small button on the right side of the step to open the build transcript.

[image]